# VueJS Template not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, components

I am struggling to get one of my template components to render. I am sure the mistake is simple but I am having trouble finding a solution since I am new to VueJS. My header shows up just fine but my Questions component is invisible. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Here is the code.
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <title>Lionsfield Placement Quiz</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">

    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js"></script>

    <style>
        .is-loading {
            background: cyan;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="space-top container shadow" align="center">
        <div id="app">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HeaderSection />
    <QuestionSection />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import HeaderSection from "./components/HeaderSection";
import QuestionSection from "./components/QuestionSection";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HeaderSection,
    QuestionSection
  }
};
</script>
```

HeaderSection.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img class="logo" src="/img/lion.png" alt />
    <h1 id="heading-top">Lionsfield English Quick Placement Quiz</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "HeaderSection"
};
</script>
```

QuestionSection.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions" v-bind:key="question.id">
      <div v-show="index === questionIndex">
        <h2 id="question-text">{{ question.text }}</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li
              class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6"
              v-for="(response, index2) in question.responses"
              v-bind:key="response.text"
            >
              <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
                <label class="btn btn-red btn-block quesion-b">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    v-bind:value="response.correct"
                    v-bind:name="index"
                    v-bind:id="index2"
                    v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"
                    v-model="userResponses[index]"
                    @click="select();next();roundProg()"
                    checked
                  />
                  {{response.text}}
                </label>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="progress">
            <div
              class="progress-bar bg-red"
              role="progressbar"
              :style="{ width: myWidth + '%' }"
              aria-valuenow="45"
              aria-valuemin="0"
              aria-valuemax="100"
            >{{prog}}%</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary mb-5 btn-sm"
          v-if="questionIndex > 0"
          v-on:click="prev();roundProg()"
        >Previous Question</button>
        <!--    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" v-on:click="next();roundProg()">
                Next Question
        </button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-show="questionIndex === quiz.questions.length">
      <h2>You did Amazing job {{quiz.user}}!!!</h2>
      <p>
        <!--Total score: {{ score() }} / {{ quiz.questions.length }}-->
        Total score: {{ score() }}%
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template >

<script>
let quiz = {
  user: "English Learner",
  questions: [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: "What _______ your job?",
      responses: [
        { text: "are" },
        { text: "is", correct: true },
        { text: "be" },
        { text: "have" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Lynn _______ at home at the moment.",
      responses: [
        { text: "works" },
        { text: "is working", correct: true },
        { text: "work" },
        { text: "are working" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "We have ______ information about that.",
      responses: [
        { text: "a lot of", correct: true },
        { text: "an" },
        { text: "any" },
        { text: "many" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      quiz: quiz,

      questionIndex: 0,

      userResponses: Array(quiz.questions.length).fill(false),
      isActive: false,
      myWidth: 0,
      prog: 0
    };
  },

  methods: {
    roundProg: function() {
      this.prog = Math.round(this.myWidth);
    },
    select: function() {
      isActive = true;
      console.log(this);
    },
    next: function() {
      this.questionIndex++;
      this.myWidth = (this.questionIndex / quiz.questions.length) * 100;
    },

    prev: function() {
      this.questionIndex--;
      this.myWidth = (this.questionIndex / quiz.questions.length) * 100;
    },

    score: function() {
      let n =
        (this.userResponses.filter(function(val) {
          return val;
        }).length /
          quiz.questions.length) *
        100;
      function truncate(num, places) {
        return Math.trunc(num * Math.pow(10, places)) / Math.pow(10, places);
      }
      return truncate(n, 2);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";


Vue.config.productionTip = false;


new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

My HeaderSection and QuestionSection are in the components folder located in the src folder

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. It is very usefull at first to open Developer Tools, and it saves more time if you use developement enviroment with lint checking like Visual Studio Code.
Must be:

```js
let quiz = {
  user: "English Learner",
  questions: [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: "What _______ your job?",
      responses: [
        { text: "are" },
        { text: "is", correct: true },
        { text: "be" },
        { text: "have" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Lynn _______ at home at the moment.",
      responses: [
        { text: "works" },
        { text: "is working", correct: true },
        { text: "work" },
        { text: "are working" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "We have ______ information about that.",
      responses: [
        { text: "a lot of", correct: true },
        { text: "an" },
        { text: "any" },
        { text: "many" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you Darius. Unfortunately, I don't see how this code prevents my component from rendering. Any more clues you could give me that might shed some light on this. Thank you.

Comment: The error was on closing object structure, some curly and square braces where too much

Comment: I see. That was when I copied the code as there are 21 questions in the original. I will edit my code. My code that I using doesn't have the extra brackets. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: The QuestionSection works as expected, it may be CSS issue